# A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause in LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

```
(from order in db.ProductOrder
 where (from cancel in db.OrderEvents
        where order.OrderId != cancel.OrderId && order.MemberId == MemberId)
 select order).ToList();
```

It shows an error:

> A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't select anything in your sub-query

```
from cancel in db.OrderEvents
where order.OrderId != cancel.OrderId && order.MemberId == MemberId
// select something here
```

Also you are passing results of this sub-query to `where` operator which expects boolean result. I assume you should call `Any()` on this sub-query. Something like:

```
(from order in db.ProductOrder
 where (from cancel in db.OrderEvents
        where order.OrderId != cancel.OrderId
        select cancel).Any() && order.MemberId == MemberId
 select order).ToList()
```

BTW lambda syntax for sub-query will be shorter in this case:

```
db.OrderEvents.Any(oe => oe.OrderId != order.OrderId)
```